# PHP include doesn't show content

Tags: php, html, include, easyphp

I'm trying to include a PHP file with plain HTML inside into another HTML file but the include is not displaying anything.

My dir tree is this:

- ROOT

  - images
  - includes

    - header.php
  - variables
  - index.html
  - style.css

I put this include in the index.html

```
<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>
```

And this is how the header PHP looks like:

```
<div id="header">
<div class="center">
    <a href="#"><img id="logo" src='images/logo.png' alt="Home" />
    </a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">INICIO</a> |</li>
        <li><a href="#">SOCIAL</a> |</li>
        <li><a href="#">MAPA DEL SITIO</a> |</li>
        <li><a href="#">RSS</a> |</li>
        <li><a href="#">LOGIN</a> |</li>
        <li><a href="#">REGISTRO</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note: I'm using EasyPHP under Windows7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try renaming your file to index.php. ;)

By the way, use quotes around the dir/file. `include('bla.php');`

Comment: At last, It's wornking, thank you. I was following a tutorial here http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/how-to-create-php-website-template/ that uses index.html and puts the include inside it. I'm using the single quotes it was just a typo while writing here.

Comment: what  the difference between single and double quote for me double quote is working fine

Comment: Updated my answer to 'quotes'. I use single quotes, but you can use double quotes as well of course.

Answer (score 1):

index.html can not know the code of php;
You should change it to index.php

Answer (score 1):

You can run php code into html file but you need to make .htaccess file into your document root directory and put following line of code into .htaccess file

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

OR

AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

Then, run your html file.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like this inside the `header.php` file:

```
<?php
echo <<<OUTPUT
<div id="header">
  <div class="center">
      <a href="#"><img id="logo" src='images/logo.png' alt="Home" />
      </a>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#">INICIO</a> |</li>
          <li><a href="#">SOCIAL</a> |</li>
          <li><a href="#">MAPA DEL SITIO</a> |</li>
          <li><a href="#">RSS</a> |</li>
          <li><a href="#">LOGIN</a> |</li>
          <li><a href="#">REGISTRO</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
OUTPUT;
?>
```

That way, you can also embed some PHP variables inside your HTML code (when using `echo` and the `heredoc` syntax).

You have to be careful about the `heredoc` syntax: you mustn't leave any whitespace characters before the first and after the last `OUTPUT`. And of course, change the extension of your `index.html` file to `php`.

The next thing you should do is use quotes when specifying the path of the file to be included: `include("includes/header.php");`.

You have also forgot to put a closing tag for the `<div id="header">` element in your `HTML` code, but that is less important for the issue itself. :-)